# Adding a partition from another DB to existing partitioned table in Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, sharding, foreign-table

**Short description of a problem**

I need to build a partitioned table "users" with 2 partitions located on separate servers (Moscow and Hamburg), each partition is table with columns:
`id` - integer primary key with auto increment
`region` - smallint partition key, which equals either 100 for Hamburg or 200 for Moscow
`login` - unique character varying with length of 100.

I intended to make sequences for `id` as `n*1000 + 100` for Hamburg, and `n*1000 + 200` for Moscow, so just looking on primary key I will know which partition it belongs to.

`region` is intended to be read only and never change after creation, so no records will move between partitions.

`SELECT` queries must be able to return records from all partitions and `UPDATE` queries must be able to modify records on all partitions, `INSERT`/`DELETE` queries must be able to add/delete records only to local partition, so data stored in them is not completely isolated.

**What was done**

Using pgAdmin4

1. I created a "test" table on Hamburg server, added all column info, marked it as partitioned table with partition key `region` and partition type `List`.
2. I created a "hamburg" partition in this table, adding primary key constraint as `id`,`region` and unique key constraint as `login`,`region`.
3. I created a "moscow" table on Moscow server with the same column info as "test"
4. I added `postgres_fdw` extension to Hamburg server, created Foreign server pointing to DB on Moscow server and User mapping.
5. I added "moscow" foreign table to Hamburg server pointing to "moscow" table on Moscow server.

**What is my problem**

I couldn't figure out how to attach this foreign table as second partition to "test" table.

When I tried to `attach` partition through pgAdmin dialog in "test" table partitions properties it shows me an error: `cannot unpack non-iterable Response object`

When I tried to add partition with query as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE public.test ATTACH PARTITION public.moscow FOR VALUES IN (200);
```

It shows me an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot attach foreign table "moscow" as partition of partitioned table "test"
DETAIL:  Table "test" contains unique indexes.
SQL state: 42809
```

I removed unique constraint from `login` column but it shows the same error.

When I make partitioned table with the same properties and both partitions initially located on the same server all works well, except for postgres watch for `login` uniqueness per-partition rather than in whole table, but I suggest this is its limitation.

So, how can I attach a table located on the second server as partition to partitioned table located on the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: Since you cannot create an index on a partitioned table, PostgreSQL cannot create a partition of the unique index. But the unique index is required to implement the constraint.

See this source comment:

```
/*
 * If we're attaching a foreign table, we must fail if any of the indexes
 * is a constraint index; otherwise, there's nothing to do here.  Do this
 * before starting work, to avoid wasting the effort of building a few
 * non-unique indexes before coming across a unique one.
 */
```

Either drop the unique constraint or don't use foreign tables as partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was finally able to add a foreign table as partition to partitioned table.

1. It was necessary to drop `primary key` property on `id` and `unique` property on `login` columns for **partitioned table**
2. After that I was able to attach foreign table as partition to partitioned table
3. Later I have added `primary key` property on `id` and `unique` property on `login` columns for each **local partition**.

So in the end I have unique global `id` as it is generated by sequences for each DB with never intersected values. For `login` uniqueness I have to manually check global table if there is any record with it before inserting.

P.S. Hopefully, this partitioning mechanism in postgres is suitable for geographically distant regions.